# Laravel - Ternery operator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am laravel beginer. i am not able to understand this code.

```
<option value="1" {{ !empty($make->status)?($make->status==1)? 'selected':'':'selected' }} >Active
```

please help with if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
!empty($make->status)?($make->status==1)? 'selected':'':'selected'
```

can be written out in long form as

```
if (!empty($make->status) {
    if ($make->status == 1) {
        echo "selected";
    }
    else {
    }
else {
    echo "selected";
}
```

So the option will be selected if `$make->status` is empty, or if it's not empty and its value is 1.

As written, the code is relying on operator precedence and would be much easier to understand if it was written with parentheses:

```
!empty($make->status) ? ($make->status==1 ? 'selected':'') : 'selected'
```